# TypeError: Cannot read property 'DASH' of undefined

Tags: node.js, angular, api, express

In my current project I would like to display some data (crypto-statistics). By calling an API I have a working response.

My environment is:

Node: 8.9.5,
Express: 4.16.4,
Angular CLI: 7.3.6,
Typescript: 3.2.4, 
OS: darwin x64

Here is my code:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const request = require('request')
const cors = require('cors')

// Create an express app
const app = express()

// Error-fix: Cross-Origin
app.use(cors())

ticker = "DASH";

// Define a default route handler for the Node app
app.get('/getDetails', (req, res) => {
    let options = {
        'url': 'https://api-call-something.io/',
        'formData': {"access-token": "xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx", "ticker": ticker},
        'method': "POST"
    }; 

    request(options).pipe(res);
})
```

This is my response:

RESPONSE:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": {
        "DASH": {
            "semantic_version": "0.12.3.3",
            "last_block": 982197,
            "block_age": 446554,
            "statuses": {
                "ENABLED": 4898,
                "SENTINEL_PING_EXPIRED": 11,
                "NEW_START_REQUIRED": 46,
                "UPDATE_REQUIRED": 60,
                "PRE_ENABLED": 1,
                "POSE_BAN": 1
            },
            "usd_price": 111.50325810328,
            "btc_price": "0.02107716",
            "change_24h": -2.42056,
            "roi": 6.77475551,
            "collateral": 1000,
            "payout_sum_daily": "909.11649250",
            "payout_count_daily": 543,
            "payout_period": 779350.464,
            "daily_income": {
                "coin": 0.1856,
                "btc": "0.00391213",
                "usd": 20.6961
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to access usd_price value I get an error:

```
app.get('/getDetails', (req, res) => {
    let options = {
        'url': 'https://api-call-something.io/',
        'formData': {"access-token": "xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx", "ticker": ticker},
        'method': "POST"
    };

    request(options).pipe(res);

    usd = res.message['DASH'].usd_price;

    console.log(usd);
    console.log(res);
})
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'DASH' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure if you see that ticker is not declared as a variable in the global scope. Calling it will definitely return undefined.
Same thing with the usd declaration. You cannot log an undeclared variable to the console it will definitely return undefined.

Refactored code for you:

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");
const cors = require("cors");

// Create an express app
const app = express();

// Error-fix: Cross-Origin
app.use(cors());

const ticker = "DASH";

// Define a default route handler for the Node app
app.get("/getDetails", (req, res) => {
  let options = {
    url: "https://api-call-something.io/",
    formData: { "access-token": "xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx", ticker: ticker },
    method: "POST"
  };

  request(options).pipe(res);

  const usd = res.message.DASH.usd_price;

  console.log(usd);
  console.log(res);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
    let message = res['message'];
    let dash = Object.keys(message)[0];
    let jsonObject: any = message[dash];
    console.log("USD Price: " + jsonObject['usd_price']);
```

Comment: Thank you. I get the same undefined error

`
TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined
`

Comment: What do you get in your `console.log(res);`?

Comment: By adding console.log(usd) or console.log(res), I didn't get any log in my browser. Just an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined

Comment: That is because your error is thrown before it calls the console logs. Try to move the logs before the line with the error, this will trigger your logs

Comment: I put it before "let message = res[0]["message"];". TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to `pipe` `res` into the request? What are you trying to achieve by doing that?

`pipe` is used for things like file uploads or sending raw data to the api, which I don't think you need as you are already sending `formData`.

Try changing the code to this:

```
app.get('/getDetails', (req, res) => {
    let options = {
        'url': 'https://api-call-something.io/',
        'formData': {"access-token": "xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx", "ticker": ticker},
        'method': "POST"
    };

    // Call request and handle response in callback
    request(options, (err, response, body) => {
      if (err || response.statusCode !== 200) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(response.statusCode).send(err.message);
        return
      }
      const usd = body.message.DASH.usd_price;

      console.log(usd);

      // Send whatever response you want
      res.send(usd)
    })
})
```

Comment: Hello braza! I'm not sending formdata. My plan is to call the API-data and make a copy into my MongoDB.

I only need a few values, not all. That's why I want to call them individually.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. Have you tried running my suggested code to see what you get from `console.log(usd)`? `usd` should be defined on that line, so you can do whatever you want with it at that point, such as adding it to MongoDB.

Comment: When I add your code and open http://localhost:3000/getDetails, I get an error: 

This page isn’t working, localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: I've updated the code so it sends an error response if the request fails, as that seems like the issue. What do you get now?

Comment: I've updated my code also. I get the same error: localhost didn’t send any data. :(